# Cannot get DONE button on UITextField to work

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I cannot seem to get the DONE button on the keyboard to dismiss the keyboard? Anyone know how to make it work?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that you have properly set the delegate for the `UITextField`?

Comment: Seems you perhaps are confusing text fields with text views? In any case make sure the delegates are set up correctly. Also see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code, in particular resigning first responder of the textfield in `-textFieldShouldReturn` is fine.

I think you probably didn't hook things up correctly, possibly forgetting to set the delegate of your `UITextField`.

A snippet from a recent project of mine where I used a Next return key and a Done return key for two fields, toggling from the first to the second, and dismissing the second (which had a Done return key):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if(textField == self.nameTextField)
        [self.descriptionTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Concerning `UITextView` (your question specifically mentions `UITextField` in the title but your code has both for textfield and textview), you will need to resign first responder differently.

Since Text views are for longer text entry including multiple lines where you can also use the return key for a line break, you'll have to detect when the user changes the text. 
If they try to enter a line break, then manually resign at that point. 
Example follows:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
        shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
         [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```